# I want this code to insert data into same row of database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want this code to insert data into same row of database table but instead it creating another row into table and inserting second value in to second row.

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
$numbers = count($_POST["name"]);  
if($numbers > 0)  
{  
    for($i=0; $i<$numbers; $i++)  
    {  
        if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))  
        {  
            $sql = "ALTER TABLE 
                    tbl_name 
                    ADD COLUMN name_$i varchar(100) 
                    ";

            mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            $number = (!empty($numbers[$i])) ? $numbers[$i] : '';

            // $user_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
            // echo $user_id;

            print_r($_POST["name"][$i]);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (name_$i) VALUES ('". mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i]) ."')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        }  
    }  
    echo "Data Inserted";  
}  
else  
{  
    echo "Please Enter Name";  
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want to update a row you have to use an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Jay I tried but that didn't work

Comment: You tried an update? Show us that query.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE tbl_name SET name_$i = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i]) ."'";

Comment: It appears that you add a column for each name. Without details it's hard to say for sure but that's very likely wrong to begin with.

Comment: I agree with @stickybit, we don't have enough information but it would seem this design doesn't make too much sense, therefore you may be overcomplicating what you need to do. There are practical limits to the number of columns you can have in a table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL's `INSERT` statement is used for adding rows to a table.

If you want to update an existing row instead, use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET [attribute] = [value] WHERE [condition]
```

Answer (score -1):

You using Insert and Alter they are not for update, for this use the Update stmt (statement) UPDATE table where..

Comment: he's putting a alter table adding a new colunm inside a looping, after that he's saying that he want to insert, and insert will insert a new row always, he should just create this colunm and update it.

Comment: We've already said that more than once. Have you read the comments or the answer provided? `ALTER` creates the column.